# Azure devops API - Get diff between two branches

Tags: c#, azure-devops, git-branch

How would you compare two branches in Azure repository and fetch the ahead and/or behind commits ?

Ideally using the Azure API and or C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the [Azure DevOPs API Diff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/diffs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/diffs/commits?api-version=6.0
```

Example between branches:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/MyProject/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/diffs/commits?baseVersion=develop&targetVersion=master&api-version=6.0
```

Once a simple curl is working, you can encapsulate it in a C# program, or check the [Azure DevOps .NET client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks for referring this. I used `GetCommitDiffsAsync` but the response just contains the diff commit count and not the details (even Id is not present). Is there any other API I shall get this info as well.

Comment: @Nithya I would try a simple curl, before https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.githttpclientbase.getcommitdiffsasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet

Comment: ```{
changeCounts: {
Edit: 256,
Add: 34,
Delete: 83
},
changes: [
{
item: {
objectId: "some-guid",
originalObjectId: "some-guid",
gitObjectType: "tree",
commitId: "some-guid",
path: "/src",
isFolder: true,
url: "{change_url}"
},
changeType: "edit"
}
],
commonCommit: "some-guid",
baseCommit: "some-guid",
targetCommit: "some-guid",
aheadCount: 51,
behindCount: 9
}```

This is the response structure I get by either Curl / GetCommitDiffsAsync API => I am not seeing all the diff commit details. Ahead, behind and just the base commit id and its changes alone comes.

Comment: @Nithya Indeed, I don't see the level of details you want in the normal payload. Not sure said details would be available.